# ExpandableListView items are not clickable

Tags: java, android, android-layout

There is the following code:

```
    @Override
    public void showDialog(final Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_year_days, null);
        ExpandableListView list=(ExpandableListView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialogYearDaysList);
        SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter=new 
            SimpleExpandableListAdapter(context, createGroups(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, 
            new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, createChildren(), 
            R.layout.list_item_day_of_year, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.listItemDayOfYearName});
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setClickable(true);
        list.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "123", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

        });
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setTitle("Choose days");
        builder.create().show();
    }

    public List<Map<String, ?>> createGroups() {
        List<Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>();            
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put("name", DAYS[i]);
            list.add(item);
        }           
        return list;
    }

    public List<List<Map<String, ?>>> createChildren() {
        List<List<Map<String, ?>>> list = new ArrayList<List<Map<String,?>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            List<Map<String, ?>> itemList = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < COUNT_OF_DAYS[i]; j++) {
                Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                item.put("name", String.valueOf(j+1));
                itemList.add(item);
            }
            list.add(itemList);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

This code works and shows me my ExpandableListView, but there is the following problem - child items aren't clickable! As you can see, I've set listener for click by child, but I've never seen any Toasts! How can I fix it?

UPDATE: I use my custom view for child item, but if I change it for any android.R.layout layout it will work!

Comment: "if I change it for any android.R.layout layout it will work!" Post your custom layout, it probably consumes the touch event before it reaches the OnChildClickListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:focusable="false"` for each view in your custom view for child item.

Answer (score -1):

In Adapter class return true from overridden method ischild selectable.
 Do this it worked for me.